# How to generate a parent-children nested data structure in ruby

Tags: ruby

How to generate a parent-children nested data structure in ruby?

```rb
def get_data_tree
  @zones = Zone.select(:parent_id, :id, :name).all
  @result = []
  @zones.each do |zone|
    ap zone[:name]
    ap "*" * 10
    zone         = zone.as_json.with_indifferent_access
    zone[:label] = zone[:name] unless zone.include? :label

    @result << zone if zone[:parent_id].nil?
    @zones.each do |item|
      item = item.as_json.with_indifferent_access
      next if item[:id] == zone[:id]
      if item[:parent_id] == zone[:id]
        item[:label]    = item[:name] unless item.include? :label
        zone[:children] = [] unless zone.include? :children
        ap item[:name]
        ap "-" * 10
        zone[:children] << item
        ap zone
      end
    end
  end

  @result
end
```

generate data to supply with element ui
https://element.eleme.cn/#/zh-CN/component/cascader

when i use perl code with same logic can generate the data structure, please give some advice , many thanks

Comment: you appear to have `@zones.each` within another `@zones.each`, and you also seem to be overwriting `zone` inside the code, after using it incorrectly in the `ap zone[:name]` code ... what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: What are you trying to do? Perhaps perform a [self join](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_self.asp) on the database table?

Comment: I wanna generate Deep recursive data structure to fit the vue element ui , data structure like this [ name: 'cisco', pid: nil, id:1, children [ {name: 'switch', pid: 1, id:2},{name: 'router', pid: 1, id:3},{name: 'firewall', pid: 1, id:4}]

Answer (score 1):

Your logic looks like it *almost* works, but you've messed it up by introducing a new `@result` variable, which only stores `zones` with no parent ID. Here is a simplified, fixed implementation:

```
def get_data_tree
  @zones = Zone.select(:parent_id, :id, :name).all.map do |zone|
    zone.as_json.with_indifferent_access.merge(children: [], label: zone.name)
  end


  @zones.each do |zone|
    next if zone[:parent_id].nil?
    @zones.select { |zone| zone[:parent_id] == zone[:id] }
      .each { |child_zone| zone[:children] << child_zone }
  end

  @zones
end
```

Comment: Unlike your original implementation, this doesn't ignore scenarios where a zone's parent is itself. I'm not sure if that was an intentional decision, but would be quite easy to re-add if desired. (However, if that's invalid, you should probably enforce this via some validation rules instead!)